# How do Cattails choose their targets?

Tags: plants-vs-zombies

Cattails can attack any lane of zombies, not just that which they're planted in. So how do they choose which zombie to attack?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure, but whenever I used them they seem to attack zombies in this order:

- Whatever is attacking it (self-preservation, although this could just be point 3 below as well)
- Balloon zombies if any appear
- Zombies that are the furthest down a particular lane
- Pick a target at random (if they're all nomming on Wall-nuts)

Comment: Point 1 is probably due the zombie's hitbox intercepting any cattail projectiles that would heading elsewhere. This, of course, is assuming that PvZ uses a hitbox system, because I have no clue.

Comment: @Yawus - PvZ definitely uses hitboxes, you can see the effect if you place a plant in the space a zombie already occupies - it'll stop where it is and start eating (it's within the hitbox), whereas zombies behind it stop a little ways away to eat (they hit the edge of the hitbox). As for the projectiles getting intercepted, I don't think it's likely, because the projectiles ignore other zombies on their way to the balloon zombie, making me think they simply 'lock-on' to their intended target and ignore anything in between

Comment: @Yawus not 100% sure about hitboxes in this case, as cattails will clearly weave into different lanes and (if I recall correctly) ignore other targets on their way to the correct lane